# php: add variable into input tag with date type

Tags: date, input

I have a problem with displaying "app_date" variable into input tag with date type.

Part of code:

```
<input type="date" name="app_date" value="<?php echo $loan['app_date']; ?>">
```

With text type, there is no any problems and everything displays correctly. How to fix it that it will work with date type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `print_r($loan['app_date']);` instead of echo

or maybe:

```
<input type="date" name="app_date" value="<?php echo date($loan['app_date']); ?>">
```

Sorry I don't fully understand the problem, what prints out on the html side?

Ok, I understand now, I think the date you are giving is in the wrong format for HTML

Check this page:

[Input type DateTime - Value format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854874/input-type-datetime-value-format)

If you format $loan["app_date"] correctly then the html should be able to parse and display it properly :)

Comment: app_date has value, as I said tve value of this variable is possible to see everywhere beside into the input with type DATE.

Comment: In HTML I see: <input type="date" name="app_date" value="11.08.2012"> But it displays default tip into the field like Day.Month.Year. Maybe this tip overcover my value? But how to fix it?

Comment: Please see this link, I have changed my answer to reflect this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854874/input-type-datetime-value-format