# html5 datetime-local not showing up value on update form

Tags: php, html, datetime

I have an update form with `html5` elements to update a row of data from table. All the elements are showing the current corresponding data in table except the `datetime-local` `input` element. Even the `date`, `week` and `month` element are working.

The data for that field is saved in database in a column with `datetime` type. This is a sample of data stored in that column.

> 2014-05-15 12:58:00

How can I make the `datetime-local` `input` element to show the current value on database. Do I have to format this value in some other way for that ( like `d/m/Y H:i a` or something)

Here is the code for that element

```
$html_form .= "<tr><td class='form_left'>".$label." : </td><td class='form_right'><input type='datetime-local' name='birth_day' id='birth_day' value='".$row_data['birth_day']."' /> </td></tr>";
```

Need to solve this issue as fast as possible. I am stuck with it right now.

Please help me find a solution. I can't finish my current project without fixing it.

Comment: Your tags name technologies that span, like, _all_ of a web application. Narrow down your problem to just one of them, please.

Comment: Sorry, I added php, html5 and mysql since this code include all three (value of an 'html5' element taken from 'mysql' database using 'php' not showing up). Will remove html5 and mysql if you want.

Comment: Narrow down your problem to _one_ technology. Abstract. Debug.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854874/input-type-datetime-value-format

Comment: @prisoner. Thank you so much it worked. The third answer in the link. :) strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', strtotime($my_datetime_input))

Comment: Did you notice that `datetime` and `datetime-local` were dropped from the latest draft? See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reformatted the `datetime` data in the table with the following code.

```
$birth_day = strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', strtotime($row_data['birth_day']));
```

Then provided that reformatted value as the value of `datetime-local` `input` element.

```
$html_form .= "<tr><td class='form_left'>".$label." : </td><td class='form_right'><input type='datetime-local' name='birth_day' id='birth_day' value='".$birthday."' /> </td></tr>";
```

Then it started showing the current value from database.