# How to set the HTML datetime input a value by default

Tags: php, html, datetime, input

For example, I have a textbox in which I want to set by default a value from database. I can do it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="abcd" value="<?=@$result['xyz'];?>"/>
```

Ok, it works for this type of field.

But, I want to do it for a date-time field like this:

```
$datetime = $result['datetime']; 
//already converted to format("d/m/Y, h:i:s A")
<input type="datetime-local" value="<?=@$datetime?>" name="abc"/>
```

I've already tried converting the database date-time format to fit this format. No result.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it would help to convert the date to [this format](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime-local.html#input.datetime-local.attrs.value)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input type DateTime - Value format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854874/input-type-datetime-value-format)

Comment: @nhee agreed, also mentioned in the post there, the correct DateTime format for php is Y-m-d\TH:i:sP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
$datetime = new DateTime($result['datetime']);

<input type="datetime-local" value="<?= $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>" name="abc" />
```

This will always try to format your date and time to a correct format. If this fails, PHP will throw an exception letting you know what's wrong.