# Change date format from default

Tags: asp.net, html

I have one problem. In code I have set the format for display the date time as below image:

[image]

But the result still show as below format:

[image]

How can I change the format for this problem.

Comment: Can you please post the code instead of images?

Comment: try to type="datetime" instead of type="datetime-local".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input type DateTime - Value format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854874/input-type-datetime-value-format)

Answer (score 0):

**You can't change this format**

It gets the format from the OS. The input format will be varying depending on the international settings of the OS. It could also depend on the browser and the OS of the client computer too.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format) question

> We have to differentiate between the over the wire format and the
> browser's presentation format.
>
> Wire format The HTML5 date input specification [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format) refers to the
> RFC3339 specification [2], which specifies a full-date format equal
> to: yyyy-mm-dd. See section 5.6 of the RFC3339 specification for more
> details.
>
> Presentation format Browsers are unrestricted in how they present a
> date input. At the time of writing Chrome has the most extensive date
> support [3]. It displays a date picker using the user's local calendar
> format. Opera (v10.6+) also displays a date picker, but shows the date
> in the wire format. Other browsers, such as Firefox 24 and Internet
> Explorer 9/10 display a text input field with the wire format.
>
> **References**
>
> 1 http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html
>
> 2 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339
>
> 3 https://plus.google.com/102860501900098846931/posts/hTcMLVNKnec

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using pure HTML, You can use combination of `jQuery` and [Masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) like

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"mm/dd/yyyy"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use the

`String.Format` method

something like this:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format(yourDate.ToLongDateString(), "dd/MM/yy"))
```