# Django DateTimeField ValidationError: value has an invalid format

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting a validation error when trying to store a date time in a django DateTimeField.

The format I'm trying to save is below, together with the error. :

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'Mon, 23 May 2016 08:30:15 GMT' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][T
```

In my django settings I have:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ("%d %b %Y", )
```

Should I be converting the format before saving or can I add to `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`

Comment: DATE_INPUT_FORMATS is for DateField not DateTimeField

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django references: [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield)

Here's the answer: [StackOverflow Answer Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855090/1990671)

Comment: I tried to get it to a valid format using `>>> from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime`
`>>> parse_datetime('Mon, 23 May 2016 08:30:15 GMT')` but that just returns a blank result - no errors bizarrely? What's the best way to convert the format?

Comment: `>>> from datetime import datetime`
    `date_object = datetime.strptime('Mon, 23 May 2016 08:30:15 GMT', '%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
`

try in this way.

Comment: Thanks that gives a naive date time error even though GMT is specified?

Comment: That GMT is supported. I used that list
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

and it works !!!
`datetime.strptime('Mon, 23 May 2016 08:30:15 GMT', '%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')`

Yes, its from standard python library.

Comment: Bizarre I still get the naive date time warning. The parsing doesn't seem to deal with the timezone `>>> datetime.strptime('Mon, 23 May 2016 08:30:15 GMT', '%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 23, 8, 30, 15)`

Comment: How do you get time warning?

Comment: Django outputs the error (using 1.9) if timezone aware in settings. See this: https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/8005-london-django-april-meetup