# How can I write a editable time code in Javascript in the same input field as Datepicker, but without using Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I myself wrote this particular code to get the current time:

```
$(function() {
    function getCurrentTime() {
        var CurrentTime = "";
        try {
            var CurrentDate = new Date();
            var CurrentHours = CurrentDate.getHours();
            var CurrentMinutes = CurrentDate.getMinutes();
            var CurrentSeconds = CurrentDate.getSeconds();

            if (CurrentMinutes < 10) { CurrentMinutes = "0" + CurrentMinutes; }
            if (CurrentSeconds < 10) { CurrentSeconds = "0" + CurrentSeconds; }
            if (CurrentHours < 10) { CurrentHours = "0" + CurrentHours; }

            CurrentTime = "" + CurrentHours + ":" + CurrentMinutes + ":" + CurrentSeconds + "";
        }
        catch (ex) {
        }
        return CurrentTime;
    }
```

and the only way I managed to show in the same input field as datepicker was this:

```
$(".class").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "dd.mm.yyyy" + " " + getCurrentTime(),
}
```

This is all fine and well, but I cannot edit the content of the time, as when the datepicker closes it always returns the current time. Please help my find a way around this, WITHOUT using another plug in.

Comment: So you want the functionality of a date _and_ time picker, but for some reason you refuse to use the right plugin for the job to begin with? Makes little sense to me.

Comment: I don't have access to the ftp where I can add more files and plug ins, I am restricted with the current code...

Comment: so you can add your code but cannot add anything else? Sounds weird

Comment: If I understand correctly, the time is input manually by the user? No clicking to select it, right?

Comment: it is inputed automatically, it always returns the current time only, whenever you select a specific date.

Comment: You don't want to add all the functionality of a time picker because [time is hard](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time). Find a CDN that hosts the time picker, add it to the top of your JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood what your goal is. Should the user input manually the time?

This change in the getCurrentTime function will check if in the datepicker current value there is a "time" part - if there is such time part, it will use that text instead of recomputing it.

Could be buggy since I've had no chance to try it, but this could be a possible solution. Not the best since using that "format" property isn't the best way to achieve this, but it should work.

```
$(function() {
    function getCurrentTime() {
        var CurrentTime = "";
        try {
            var currTime = undefined;
            var currVal = $('#my-datepicker').val();
            if (currVal.length > 11) {
                currTime = currVal.substring(11, 8);
            }
            if (typeof currTime !== 'undefined' && currTime.length == 8) {
                CurrentTime = currTime;
            } else {


                var CurrentDate = new Date();
                var CurrentHours = CurrentDate.getHours();
                var CurrentMinutes = CurrentDate.getMinutes();
                var CurrentSeconds = CurrentDate.getSeconds();

                if (CurrentMinutes < 10) { CurrentMinutes = "0" + CurrentMinutes; }
                if (CurrentSeconds < 10) { CurrentSeconds = "0" + CurrentSeconds; }
                if (CurrentHours < 10) { CurrentHours = "0" + CurrentHours; }

                CurrentTime = "" + CurrentHours + ":" + CurrentMinutes + ":" + CurrentSeconds + "";
            }
        }
        catch (ex) {
        }
        return CurrentTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

IF i understand the problem correctly, HTML5 input type "date" is one of easiest  solution which work without any plugin.
The `<input type="date">` is used for input fields that should contain a date.

example :
`<input type="date" name="bday" min="2000-01-02">`

One similar post with solution is there
[Input type DateTime - Value format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854874/input-type-datetime-value-format)