# How to change format of input type="datetime-local"?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to change the placeholder or the format of input type="datetime-local"
how can I change it from `mm/dd/yyyy` to `dd/mm/yyyy` using plain javascript or html input tag?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input type DateTime - Value format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854874/input-type-datetime-value-format)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/datetime-local the solution is on this page

Comment: It is impossible to change the format https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/input.datetime-local.html

Comment: @RapSherlock, that link is broken.  Any idea where it went?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski here https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/input.datetime-local.html

Answer (score 2):

you can do it this way :

```js
function nowAsDuration(){
    return moment.duration({
        hours:   moment().hour(),
        minutes: moment().minute(),
        seconds: moment().second()
    });
}


$("input").on("change", function() {
    var a = moment(this.value);
    var b = nowAsDuration();
    var c = a.add(b);
    
        
    this.setAttribute("my-date", c.format( this.getAttribute("my-date-format") )
    )
}).trigger("change")
```

```css
input {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px; height: 20px;
    color: white;
}

input:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px; left: 3px;
    content: attr(my-date);
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" my-date="" my-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY, hh:mm:ss" value="2015-08-09">
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar example in codepen [Simple Bootstrap datepicker](https://codepen.io/milz/pen/xbXpWw).
Using this you can show date-time in any format as per your requirement.
The only issue in the above example is that the user can enter any character inside the input field since the input type is ***text***.

I just added ***onkeydown="return false"*** so that the user will not be able to enter the data directly by clicking the input field and also added a CSS to remove the blinking cursor.

**Note**: Click "Full page" or use "Arrow keys" to view the entire calendar while running the code snippet.

Hope this helps!

```js
$(function() {
  var bindDatePicker = function() {
    $(".date").datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A',
      icons: {
        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
        down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
      }
    }).find('input:first').on("blur", function() {
      // check if the date is correct. We can accept dd-mm-yyyy and yyyy-mm-dd.
      // update the format if it's yyyy-mm-dd
      var date = parseDate($(this).val());

      if (!isValidDate(date)) {
        //create date based on momentjs (we have that)
        date = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A');
      }

      $(this).val(date);
    });
  }

  var isValidDate = function(value, format) {
    format = format || false;
    // lets parse the date to the best of our knowledge
    if (format) {
      value = parseDate(value);
    }

    var timestamp = Date.parse(value);

    return isNaN(timestamp) == false;
  }

  var parseDate = function(value) {
    var m = value.match(/^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)?(\d{1,2})(\/|-)?(\d{4})$/);
    if (m)
      value = m[5] + '-' + ("00" + m[3]).slice(-2) + '-' + ("00" + m[1]).slice(-2);

    return value;
  }

  bindDatePicker();
});
```

```css
input[type="text"]{
    color : transparent;
    text-shadow : 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.3/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.min.js
"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.3/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    Date formats: yyyy-mm-dd, yyyymmdd, dd-mm-yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy, ddmmyyyyy
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy --:-- --" onkeydown="return false" />
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not use jquery, Do you have sample codes using plain javascript or vue.js?

Answer (score 1):

please check bellow attachments. browser used date format to display in input of date, datetime, datetime-local by system date and its format.
to change please change the date format of your system and restart computer
i am sharing some images that help you to change date format
[image: 1. go to control panel and click on Date and Time]

[image]

[image]
[image]

if you not found desire date format in date time you can use advance setting option to create your own format

in this way I have solved my problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32150306)

Answer (score 1):

Input type="datetime-local has pattern property. You can set any valid pattern.

MDN Example

```
pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"

<input id="party" type="datetime-local" name="partydate"
           min="2017-06-01T08:30" max="2017-06-30T16:30"
           pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new to Vue.js. I tried something, please take a look into this...

```js
// Initialize as global component
Vue.component('date-picker', VueBootstrapDatetimePicker);

// Using font-awesome 5 icons
$.extend(true, $.fn.datetimepicker.defaults, {
  icons: {
    time: 'far fa-clock',
    date: 'far fa-calendar',
    up: 'fas fa-arrow-up',
    down: 'fas fa-arrow-down',
    previous: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
    next: 'fas fa-chevron-right',
    today: 'fas fa-calendar-check',
    clear: 'far fa-trash-alt',
    close: 'far fa-times-circle'
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    date: null,
    options: {
      // https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A',
      useCurrent: false,
      showClear: true,
      showClose: true,
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts@1.0.9/css/fontawesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts@1.0.9/css/fa-solid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts@1.0.9/css/fa-regular.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/pc-bootstrap4-datetimepicker@4.17.50/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.18.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pc-bootstrap4-datetimepicker@4.17.50/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker@5"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="h3">
        Vue bootstrap 4 date-time picker
      </h1>
      <date-picker name="date" v-model="date" :config="options" onkeydown="return false"></date-picker>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am posting this as a separate answer so that if someone wants jquery Datetimepicker they can use the first answer.

Answer (score -1):

### Default it's showing in dd/mm/yyyy format

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="date">
```

Comment: This isn't the default to me

Comment: This is same as system time format

Comment: 1) That's not what was asked. 2) It's showing as "dd. mm. lll" for me.

Comment: It depends on your local date format according to the device settings.