# Change HTML5 Datetime-Local Picker format

Tags: html

I am using an HTML5 `datetime-local` picker, by default, the format is `mm/dd/yy` now I want to change the format to `Y-m-d H:i:s`. Is there any possible solution to change this?

Code:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="fetch_date" className="form-control"/>
```

By default it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change format of input type="datetime-local"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58333728/how-to-change-format-of-input-type-datetime-local)

Comment: No, I want to change the whole format to ` Y-m-d H:i:s.`

Comment: use `jquery datetime picker`

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly you should be able to achieve this if you add the following to your code.

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="fetch_date" className="form-control" 
        placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" value=""
        min="2022-04-20" max="2122-04-20">
```

Comment: have you test your code?

Comment: I want to change the format to ` Y-m-d H:i:s.` @BhargavChudasama

Comment: but this one was not an correct answer for above question