# What is the DateTime format of input type "datetime-local"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC project. I am getting date data from sql and show it in html page. Problem is, my date input is never filled up. HTML part is:

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="@Model.Date" class="inputwidth">
```

My date format from model is **day.month.year 00:00:00**

I used a couple of formats but none worked. What format should I use and how can I convert it?

Comment: `System.DateTime` has no format, it's a binary value. If `Model.Date` is a string, you have a *serious* bug. The actual value of any `input type='date-...` element is an ISO8601 date and ASP.NET automatically converts it to `DateTime`

Comment: All databases except SQLite have date types too. There's no reason to store dates as strings anywhere

Comment: Check Google's documentation on [datetime-local's value attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#value) `One thing to note is that the displayed date and time formats differ from the actual value; the displayed date and time are formatted according to the user's locale as reported by their operating system, whereas the date/time value is always formatted YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm. When the above value submitted to the server, for example, it will look like partydate=2017-06-01T08:30.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input type DateTime - Value format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854874/input-type-datetime-value-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter, but it's ISO8601. If `Model.Date` is a `DateTime` binding just works.

`System.DateTime` has no format, it's a binary value. In fact, internally the value is stored as a `long` tick count. Date types in all databases (except SQLite) don't have formats either, they're binary values as well.

The input's Value will *always* be in ISO8601 form, no matter what text is displayed. From Google's docs for [`input type='datetime-local'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#value)

> One thing to note is that the displayed date and time formats differ from the actual value; the displayed date and time are formatted according to the user's locale as reported by their operating system, whereas the date/time value is always formatted `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm`. When the above value submitted to the server, for example, it will look like `partydate=2017-06-01T08:30`.

Assuming the `Date` property is a `DateTime`, ASP.NET Core will bind its value to the `input` element's `Value` attribute and back automatically.

The name `datetime-local` is used to remind developers that the `input` element represents the end user's time, not the server's or UTC. There's no `datetime` or `datetime-UTC` type.

Comment: What could be the problem then? My Date value is type of DateTime and it's not null or empty. What I understand is, in this case, it should work. Also my database is MSSQL.

Comment: @aoiTenshi you didn't describe a problem. You asked what the format is. It's ISO8601 and the conversion from `DateTime` is handled automatically. The model's class is missing so one can only guess what it contains

Comment: Post the model class. Is `Date` a DateTime? A string?

Comment: It is Date time.

Comment: Well, it works when I change type="datetime-local" to type="datetime". I don't know why...

Comment: What browser are you using? [There's no `input="datetime"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263515/why-is-html5-input-type-datetime-removed-from-browsers-already-supporting-it/21291028) , it was removed from the HTML 5 spec 8 years ago. [The HTML spec doesn't show it as a valid type value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#states-of-the-type-attribute)

Comment: Yeah, it was not working. I solved it btw. It is not accepting DateTime, it is accepting a string. Also I formatted my DateTime like this: Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm"). It works this way.

Comment: There's no reason to do this. I noticed your code is *not* using data binding. If you used `asp-for="Date"`, MVC would bind, fill and read the value. Right now you keep doing this yourself, *converting* the DateTime value to a string when you use `@Model.Date`.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the information. I will make it that way.